# How can i add upload image function inside a ajax function?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter-2

i have a dilema here im using if else inside an ajax function i have this code

```
function submitForm() {

    offset  = jQuery('#email').offset();
    xTop    = offset.top - $(window).height()/2 ;
    posLeft = offset.left - ($(window).width()-765)/2 ;
    posTop  = offset.top;
    params = jQuery('#registration-form').serialize();
    lytebox.show({message:'Please wait...', align: 'center', closeButton: false});
    jQuery.post('ajax/register', params + '&registered=' + isRegistered, function(data) {
            data = eval('(' + data + ')');
            if(data.error) {
                    lytebox.close();
                    $('#errorHolder').remove();
                    error = data.remarks;
                    error +='<img src="images/ttip-arrow.png" id="ttip-arrow"/></div>';
                    var wrapper     = $('.wrapper');
                    var errorHolder = $('<div id="errorHolder">')
                                                      .html(error).appendTo(wrapper);;

                    errorHolder.css({
                                                            'left':posLeft,
                                                            'top':posTop-$('#errorHolder').outerHeight()
                                              })
                                       .delay(5500)
                                       .fadeOut(1000);

                    //$("html, body").animate({scrollTop : xTop},800,function(){me.focus()});
                    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,posTop-100);
                    jQuery('#email').focus();
            } else {       
                    lytebox.close();

                    //how can i add upload image here and send email function with attach image
                    $('.notification').remove();
                    $('#errorHolder').remove();
                    $('#registration-form').fadeOut(300);
                    $('.get-started').fadeIn(300);
                    $('.show-thank-you-register').fadeIn(300);


            }
    });
```

}

i want to add upload image function and email send function at else part.. please do help me

Answer (score 0):

There is a serialize constants for serializing form data.  http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

following element is not right candidate for serialization.

```
<input type="file"/>
```

Hence it can not be included in jQuery('#registration-form').serialize(); method.

so you can not use serialization of image bytes to submit image data to server.

Optionally, you may you uploadify control to upload image with ajax post call. for more information visit following url

http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

**EDIT**

Upload your image first uplodify has *onComplete* event which tells uploading is completed and  sucessfult, now you save the rest of the form based on your business requirement.

Comment: so how will i do that? upload the image first?

Comment: Exactly upload your image first, See Edit.